# When do exterior and tensor algebras commute with dual spaces?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, tensors, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a vector space, and $V^*$ is its dual space. Furthermore, let $\Lambda(V)$ be the exterior algebra of $V$, and let $T(V)$ be the tensor algebra.

When do the following two statements hold for some natural, canonical isomorphism?

- $\Lambda(V^*) \simeq \Lambda(V)^*$
- $T(V^*) \simeq T(V)^*$

It's clear they hold for finite-dimensional real vector spaces. Do they hold in the infinite-dimensional case? What about over arbitrary fields?

Comment: Do you want isomorphisms of vector spaces or do you have another structure in mind (algebra, coalegbra...) ?

Comment: I meant as algebras.

Comment: Then you should specify what the algebra structure is on $T(V)^*$ and $\Lambda(V)^*$, it's not clear (there are several structures I know of for $T(V)^*$, and I don't think I've ever ever heard of an algebra structure on $\Lambda(V)^*$).

Comment: OK, I see. Things get hairy in the infinite-dimensional case. I'd be happy to just consider them as being isomorphic as vector spaces, and if you see my response to your answer, I'd also be happy to consider individual tensor/exterior powers rather than the whole algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's pretty clear that the field $K$ does not matter in any way (if you know how to prove things for $\mathbb{R}$, then just check that you don't use any special property of this field).

Then, be careful : the statement for tensor algebras is already false for finite-dimensional vector spaces : if $V$ has finite dimension, $T(V^*)$ has countable dimension, but $T(V)^*$ has uncountable dimension. So canonical or not, there does not exist any isomorphism.

On the other hand, the result is true for exterior algebra if $V$ has finite dimension.

Let's treat the general case : since $T(V^*) = \bigoplus_n (V^*)^{\otimes n}$ and $T(V)^* = \left(\bigoplus_n V^{\otimes n}\right)^* = \prod_n \left(V^{\otimes n}\right)^*$, defining a linear map $\varphi: T(V^*)\to T(V)^*$ is canonically the same as defining linear maps $\varphi_{n,m}: (V^*)^{\otimes n}\to \left( V^{\otimes m}\right)^*$ for all $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$, which amounts to a $(n+m)$-linear form $$\widetilde{\varphi}_{n,m}: V\times\cdots \times V\times V^*\times \cdots \times V^*\to K.$$

Likewise, defining $\psi: \Lambda(V^*)\to \Lambda(V)^*$ is the same as defining $\psi_{n,m}: \Lambda^n(V^*)\to \left( \Lambda^m(V)\right)^*$, which amounts to a $(n+m)$-linear *alternating* form $$\widetilde{\psi}_{n,m}: V\times\cdots \times V\times V^*\times \cdots \times V^*\to K.$$

Then the canonical choice is to take $\varphi_{n,m}=0$ and $\psi_{n,m}=0$ if $n\neq m$, and $$\widetilde{\varphi}_{n,n}(v_1,\dots,v_n,f_1,\dots,f_n) = \prod_i f_i(v_i)$$ and $$\widetilde{\psi}_{n,n}(v_1,\dots,v_n,f_1,\dots,f_n) = Det(f_i(v_j))_{i,j}.$$

If $V$ is finite-dimensional, all $\psi_{n,n}$ are linear isomorphisms, and thus $\psi$ is an isomorphism because the direct product in $\Lambda(V)^*$ is finite, so it's a direct sum. On the other hand, if $V$ is finite-dimensional, even though the $\varphi_{n,n}$ are linear isomorphisms, $\varphi$ is not an isomorphism.

If $V$ is infinite-dimensional, then it's worse : the $\varphi_{n,n}$ and $\psi_{n,n}$ are not isomorphisms, and a fortiori neither are $\varphi$ and $\psi$.

Comment: That's a great point. I'll refine my question as follows: what about each individual exterior power and tensor power? Is the nth exterior/tensor power of the dual isomorphic in a canonical way to the dual of the nth exterior/tensor power?

Comment: My last paragraph states that at least the usual morphism $(V^*)^{\otimes n}\to (V^{\otimes n})^*$ is not an isomorphism when $V$ is infinite-dimensional (and same thing for the exterior algebra). I don't really see a solid argument to show that there does not exist any natural isomorphism, but I would be really suprised if there was one.

Comment: Thank you - and do we know if there's an injection from one to the other, similar to the injection from V to **? Also, do you have a good reference for this stuff, particularly the exterior algebra? Seems hard to find...

Comment: However, even when $\dim V<+\infty$, we have that $\bigwedge V^*$ and $(\bigwedge V)^*$ are (canonically) isomorphic only as vector spaces, right? Not as algebras. What is even the algebra structure on $(\bigwedge V)^*$? (Point-wise multiplication does not work, since it does not preserve linearity of maps.)