# What is the dual Hopf algebra of T(V)?

Tags: reference-request, tensor-products, hopf-algebras, algebras, rough-path-theory

I am reading "Geometric versus Non-Geometric Rough Paths" by Martin Hairer and David Kelly. I don't know much about Hopf algebras but $T(V)$ is the one example I'm comfortable with so far and I'm trying to understand it's dual properly.

They look at the (truncated) tensor algebra $T(V)$ as a Hopf Algebra, by giving it the shuffle product (here denoted $\varpi$ since SE doesn't have \Sha) as the product and the deconcatenation product $\Delta$ as the coproduct.

They then say that we can define a dual Hopf Algebra built up out of the dual of the $T(V)^* \cong T(V^*)$ (I believe this is true crucially only when we truncate things, else see this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1757678/when-do-exterior-and-tensor-algebras-commute-with-dual-spaces)). The dual Hopf algebra has product given by the ordinary tensor product $\otimes$, and a coproduct $\delta$ which they don't define, other than "it is dual" to the deconcatenation product.

What is $\delta$ explicitly? Are there any digestible references, specifically focusing on $T(V)$ rather than anything too obtuse/abstract? I found Reutenauer too abstract for me to find what I wanted.

I searched for a while and didn't find any explicit constructions, funnily enough, I got some interesting information from ChatGPT, which told me the dual of:

$(T(V), \varpi, \Delta)$ is the Hopf Algebra $(S(V^*), \otimes, \Delta)$, where $S$ is the *symmetric* tensor powers. Which I found rather interesting but have no idea whether this is correct. This is slightly agreeing with Hairer and Kelly in terms of $\varpi$ swapping to $\otimes$ and would explain why they didn't say much about $\delta$, if it's just the same as $\Delta$.

It also told me $(T(V), \otimes, \Delta)$ is dual to $(T(V^*), \otimes, \otimes)$ which seems a bit fishier. Id be curious to know if either of these are true.

Comment: Are you aware that a map of vector spaces $f\colon V\to W$ induces a map on the duals $W^*\to V^*$? This is called the dual map. Saying  $\delta$  "is dual" to deconcatenation is a precise definition. (Once you identify $[T(V)\otimes T(V)]^*$ with $T(V)^*\otimes T(V)^*$ in the truncated case.)

Comment: Certainly that's a precise definition but is there not a way it can be "represented" without having to appeal to duality? I suppose you could also say $\otimes$ is defined as the dual map to $\varpi$ but the first definition is far more explicit and ready to compute with.

Comment: Sure, I am just pointing out that your claim that "they don't define it" is confusing.

Comment: forget chatgpt !

Comment: Oh I don't actually believe it but it's an interesting suggestion for what I was curious about, and so far the only one.

Comment: What do you mean by "truncated" Hopf algebra? I thought the standard way of dealing with $V$ being finite-dimensional but $T(V)$ being infinite-dimensional (at least for the purposes of duality) was to redefine the meaning of the dual: the "graded dual" of a graded vector space with finite-dimensional pieces is the direct sum of the finite-dimensional duals.

Comment: I mean I'm only looking at Hopf algebra structures on tensor algebras that are truncated, not the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (graded) dual Hopf algebra to the shuffle algebra is $(T(V^*), \otimes, \delta)$ where $\delta$ is dual to the *shuffle* product in the following sense:
let's say that $\dim V=d$ and pick a basis $\{e_1,\dotsc,e_d\}$. Consider the dual basis $\{e^i,\dotsc,e^d\}$ and the induced duality pairing between $V$ and $V^*$, given by $\langle e^i,e_j\rangle=e^i(e_j)=\mathbf{1}_{i=j}$.
Extend it to a pairing between $T(V)$ and $T(V^*)$ by
$$\langle e^{i_1,\dotsc,i_n},e_{j_1,\dotsc,j_m}\rangle:=\mathbf{1}_{n=m}\prod_{k=1}^n\langle e^{i_k},e_{j_k}\rangle.$$

In order to avoid any confusion I'll use the symbol $\dot\otimes$ to denote the tensor product external to $T(V)$ (and $T(V^*)$) used in the definition of the coproduct.
Then, $\delta$ is determined by

$$\langle\delta e^{i_1,\dotsc,i_n},x\mathbin{\dot\otimes}y\rangle=\langle e^{i_1,\dotsc,i_n},x\mathbin{\varpi}y\rangle$$
for all $x,y\in T(V)$. From this one can get an expression, although is not very useful:

$$\delta e^{i_1,\dotsc,i_n}=\sum_{\substack{x,y\in T(V)\\\langle e^{i_1,\dotsc,i_n},x\mathbin{\varpi}y\rangle\neq 0}}x\mathbin{\dot\otimes}y.$$
Another expression, which you can check as an exercise, and that has a more combinatorial flavor is:
$$\delta e^{i_1,\dotsc,i_n}=\sum_{I\subset[n]}e^{I}\mathbin{\dot\otimes}e^{[n]\setminus I}$$
where the notation $e^I$ should be self-explanatory.

**Hint:** observe that $(T(V^*),\otimes)$ is the *free* associate algebra over the set $\{e^1,\dotsc,e^d\}$ and use the fact that $\delta$ must be an algebra morphism $T(V^*)\to T(V^*)\mathbin{\dot\otimes} T(V^*)$ where the codomain has the usual product $(a\mathbin{\dot\otimes}b)\otimes(a'\mathbin{\dot\otimes}b'):=(a\otimes b)\mathbin{\dot\otimes}(a'\otimes b')$. This property plus its image on the generating set ($\delta e^i=e^i\mathbin{\dot\otimes} 1+1\mathbin{\dot\otimes}e^i$) can also be taken as the definition of $\delta$. In fact, this is one way of defining it in a basis-independent way; that is, by requiring that the subspace $V^*$ is *primitive*.

PS: Forget ChatGPT!

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. To double check I interpreted your answer correctly, the dual to the deconcatenation product $\Delta$ is $\otimes$? So the coproduct of $T(V^*)$ is $\otimes$? (Or is this the product, and dualizing swaps things around?)

Comment: Dualizing swaps things around. The dual of the deconcatenation coproduct $\Delta$ is indeed the concatenation product $\otimes$. You can see this by looking at the domains, e.g. $\Delta\colon T(V)\to T(V)\mathbin{\dot\otimes} T(V)$ so that its (graded) dual must have $\Delta^*\colon T(V^*)\mathbin{\dot\otimes} T(V^*)\to T(V^*)$. Same thing for the coproduct (after taking care of either considering the graded dual or the truncated tensor algebra).